# What is returned in std::smatch and how are you supposed to use it?

Tags: c++, regex

string `"I am 5 years old"`

regex `"(?!am )\d"`

if you go to http://regexr.com/ and apply regex to the string you'll get 5.
I would like to get this result with std::regex, but I do not understand how to use match results and probably regex has to be changed as well.

```
std::regex expression("(?!am )\\d");
std::smatch match;
std::string what("I am 5 years old.");
if (regex_search(what, match, expression))
{
     //???
}
```

Comment: Your regex is not correct as `5` will never be equal to `a`. `(?!am )\d` is the same as `\d`.

Comment: I need to get a digit after a word "am" and a space.

Comment: Why not just do a regex search for `"I am (\d)+ years old"` and use the capture?

Comment: I just gave a trivial example and the goal is to port working regex to C++. In reality we have some text with a magic word followed by a space and number. I need to get that number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `std::smatch` is an instantiation of the [match_results](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) class template for matches on string objects (with `string::const_iterator` as its iterator type). The members of this class are those described for `match_results`, but using `string::const_iterator` as its `BidirectionalIterator` template parameter.

[`std::match_results`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at) supports a `operator[]`:

> If `n > 0` and `n < size()`, returns a reference to the [`std::sub_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) representing the part of the target sequence that was matched by the *n*th captured [marked subexpression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript#Sub-expressions)).
>
> If `n == 0`, returns a reference to the [`std::sub_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) representing the part of the target sequence matched by the entire matched regular expression.
>
> if `n >= size()`, returns a reference to a [`std::sub_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match) representing an unmatched sub-expression (an empty subrange of the target sequence).

In your case, `regex_search` finds *the first match only* and then `match[0]` holds the entire match text, `match[1]` would contain the text captured with the first capturing group (the fist parenthesized pattern part), etc. In this case though, your regex does not contain capturing groups.

Here, you need to use a *capturing* mechanism here since `std::regex` does not support a look*behind*. You used a lookahead that checks the text that *immediately follows* the current location, and the regex you have is not doing what you think it is.

So, use the [following code](https://ideone.com/TtPcwW):

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex expression(R"(am\s+(\d+))");
    std::smatch match;
    std::string what("I am 5 years old.");
    if (regex_search(what, match, expression))
    {
         cout << match.str(1) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the pattern is [`am\s+(\d+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/xUdfOZ/1). It is matching `am`, 1+ whitespaces, and then *captures* 1 or more digits with `(\d+)`. Inside the code, `match.str(1)` allows access to the values that are *captured* with capturing groups. As there is only one  `(...)` in the pattern, one capturing group, its ID is 1. So, `str(1)` returns the text captured into this group.

The raw string literal (`R"(...)"`) allows using a single backslash for *regex escapes* (like `\d`, `\s`, etc.).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) returns *false* upon no match. So, I think that case is covered in my code above as `match.str(1)` won't get executed if no match is found. See [this demo with no match](https://ideone.com/YEgrpJ).

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I need to call `match.str(2)` to get a digit. `match.str(1)` returns "am 5". I use VS2015 with Visual Studio 2012 (v110) platform toolset.

Comment: @Kimi It is because you might not have access to raw string literals there. If you use VS2015 toolset, you will and ` std::regex expression(R"(am\s+(\d+))");` will grab the number into Group 1. You must be using `"(am\\s+(\\d+))"`, a regular string literal where the first `(` and last `)` must not be used. Remove them and you will get the result in Group 1. `R"(am\s+(\d+))"` = `"am\\s+(\\d+)"`.

Comment: Yes, it would not compile with `R""`. I had to remove R and add extra \, but forgot to remove extra ( and ). All works, Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't have lookbehind? It  has backreferences?

Comment: @PasserBy: The default [ECMAScript regex flavor `std::regex` uses](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/) does not support lookbehinds, but it supports backreferences.

Comment: Oops, misunderstood quite a lot.

Comment: Note that the `.str(1)` isn't necessary: `match[1]` will do. And, strangely, the C++ version is more compact than the JavaScript version.